# Stop a javascript function

Tags: javascript

What I want:

1. Monitor a player to execute a function when it reach 85% of the movie - **Ok**
2. Execute a PHP script that insert some data into a Mysql table - **Ok**
3. Do this only one time (stop looping), since I want only one row in the Mysql table - **Fail**

My code:

```
jwplayer().onTime(function(evt) {
    if (evt.position > ([evt.duration] * (85/100)) && x!=1) {
        loadXMLDoc();
        var x = 1;
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the listener to run just once with every page load, or every time the video starts and plays through?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that x gets reset everytime

```
jwplayer().onTime(
    (function () {
        var check=true;
        return function(evt) {
            if (check && evt.position > ([evt.duration] * (85/100))) {
                loadXMLDoc();
                check=false;
            }
        }
    })()
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to run only once with each page load, another approach is to make a function that commits suicide.

```
(function (player) {
    var checkAndLoad = function(evt) {
        if (evt.position > (evt.duration * (85/100))) {
           loadXMLDoc();
           checkAndLoad=function(evt){};
        }
    };
    player.onTime(function(evt) {checkAndLoad(evt);});
})(jwplayer());
```

You need the extra indirection provided by the anonymous wrapper since `onTime` gets its own copy of the event listener, so overwriting `checkAndLoad` won't affect the registered listener directly.

If you want the listener to run more than once, register additional listeners that restore `checkAndLoad` at the appropriate events (e.g. the user seeks back to near the beginning).

```
(function (player) {
    var timeListener;
    function checkAndLoad(evt) {
        if (evt.position > (evt.duration * (85/100))) {
           loadXMLDoc();
           timeListener=function(evt){};
        }
    }

    timeListener = checkAndLoad;

    player.onTime(function(evt) {timeListener(evt);});

    player.onSeek(function(evt) {
        if (evt.position < (evt.duration * (15/100))) {
           timeListener=checkAndLoad;
        }            
    });
    player.onComplete(function (evt) {timeListener=checkAndLoad;});
})(jwplayer());
```

Better would be to unregister the listener, but the JW Player API doesn't currently expose the removeEventListener method.